# How There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Customer_id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

There is no `ViewData` item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key `"Customer_id"`.

view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Customer_id", null, htmlAttributes: new 
{ @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
        using (JoinEntities db = new JoinEntities())
        {
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int id = order.Customer_id;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Order");
```

The above view is throwing exception how can I resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off may I suggest you avoid using ViewData or ViewBag in favour of strongly typed View Models. This way you will have compile time safety and do not need the View to handle any type of conversions to the data down the line.

*I suspect your issue is the following:*
ViewData contains Key Value pairs([ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)), so in this case your ViewData needs to contain a Key = "Customer_id" with a list of Customer ID's in its value, so it can use the collection create the drop down list options.

```
// This should be in the Controller action method
var ListOfCustomerIDs = new string [] {"1", "2", "3"};
ViewData["Customer_id"] = ListOfCustomerIDs;
```

Refer to the article, [MVC DropDownList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc), for more information.

Comment: what is meant by ListOfCustomerIDs

Comment: ```ListOfCustomerIDs``` can be an `array/list<t>/ICollection<T>/IEnumerable<T>` of integers, strings, objects, etc. It all depends on what your data looks like that you are trying to display in your drop down list. (See updated answer)